# Safari | Big Sur | JAVA :- Capability 'acceptInsecureCerts' could not be honored

Tags: selenium, automation, testng, browser-automation, safaridriver

Code:

```
safariOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS,true);
safariOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
driver = new SafariDriver(safariOptions);
```

Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Capability 'acceptInsecureCerts' could not be honored.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
```

Environment :

```
Big Sur 11.3
Safari : Version 14.1 (16611.1.21.161.3)
```

[image]

Getting above error when running Web Automation.

Comment: Unfortunately `acceptInsecureCerts` is not supported in Safari. What do you need to use that for?

Comment: Update with screenshort..

Comment: I hit the same issue while automating mobile tests on iOS / Safari (14.1.1), Any solution yet ?